# How do I use the SourceDir MSI property in WiX?

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer

Using WiX, how can I detect if a particular file exists in the [SourceDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857) folder?

I have the following WiX fragment designed to determine whether the *Adobe Reader* installer has been distributed in the same folder as my MSI file, and if so, run it after installation.

```
<Property Id="ADOBEREADERINSTALLER">
  <DirectorySearch Id="SourceDir" Path="[SourceDir]" Depth="0" AssignToProperty="yes">
    <FileSearch
      Id="AdbeRdr810_en_US.exe"
      Name="AdbeRdr810_en_US.exe"
      MaxDate="2011-03-24T13:18:59" MaxSize="23402288" MaxVersion="1.0.0.92"
      MinDate="2011-03-24T13:18:00" MinSize="23402288" MinVersion="1.0.0.92"
    />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
<Property Id="INSTALLADOBEREADER" Value="1" />

<CustomAction
  Id         ="InstallAdobeReader"
  Property   ="ADOBEREADERINSTALLER"
  ExeCommand =""
  Execute    ="immediate"
  Return     ="asyncNoWait" />

<InstallUISequence>
  <ResolveSource After="CostInitialize"> UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR NOT Installed </ResolveSource>
</InstallUISequence>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallAdobeReader" After="InstallFinalize"> (UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE OR NOT Installed) AND ADOBEREADERINSTALLER AND INSTALLADOBEREADER </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It appears that the `AppSearch` action (which performs the `DirectorySearch` and `FileSearch`) must occur before the `ResolveSource` action (which sets the value of `SourceDir`.)  This leaves me in backwards-about situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use a custom action right after ResolveSource instead of a search. This custom action can check if the file exists and save the result in your custom installer property.

To get access to installer properties you can use a [win32 DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) or VBScript custom action.

Comment: That's made the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Assuming all of the features I want are available in VBScript, is there any advantage in using a DLL over VBScript?

Comment: Not really. Both are used the same way.

Comment: DLL's are far more robust. ( Google script custom actions are evil )