# How to remove the backslash from [SourceDir] property value

Tags: c#, wix

I am having 
`<Property Id="MsiDirectory">[SourceDir]\\</Property>` in Wix

In my custom action

```
string msiDirectory = session["MsiDirectory"];
session.Log(" msiDirectory: {0}", msiDirectory);

msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Remove(msiDirectory.Length - 1);
                session.Log(" (2): {0}", msiDirectory);

                msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Remove(msiDirectory.Length - 1);
                session.Log(" (1): {0}", msiDirectory);

                msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Remove(msiDirectory.Length - 1);
                session.Log(" (4): {0}", msiDirectory);
```

The results are:

> msiDirectory:C:\temp\\  (2): C:\temp\ (1): C:\temp\ (4): [SourceDir

Is there a way to remove the \ in C:\temp\, so that I end with C:\temp only?

---

Following the comments and suggestions,

I changed

```
<Property Id="MsiDirectory">[SourceDir]\\</Property> to 
<Property Id="MsiDirectory">[SourceDir]</Property>

string msiDirectory = session["MsiDirectory"];
    session.Log(" msiDirectory: {0}", msiDirectory);

    msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Remove(msiDirectory.Length - 1);
                    session.Log(" (2): {0}", msiDirectory);

                    msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Remove(msiDirectory.Length - 1);
                    session.Log(" (1): {0}", msiDirectory);

                    msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Remove(msiDirectory.Length - 1);
                    session.Log(" (4): {0}", msiDirectory);
```

> msiDirectory:C:\temp\ (2): [SourceDir (1): [SourceDi  (4): [SourceD

```
session.Log(" msiDirectory: {0}", msiDirectory.TrimEnd('\\'));
```

gives c:\temp\

I just want to remove the last \ in C:\temp\

Comment: Do you want "C:temp" or "C:\temp"?

Comment: Your logging must be converting the [SourceDir].  Try writing `msiDirectory` to the console to see the actual value.  If that is the case then there isn't much you can do to change it at least in the logging.

Comment: Ok, why?  FWIW, MSI standards state that all directory properties always end in a \.  It's easiest to just go with this.

Comment: I want to have C:\temp , sorry for the typo mistake.  As you can see, I am removing the last \ in every steps

Comment: @juharr can you please elaborate and guide me through your answer.  I am  new to wix and custom action

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just replace "\" with empty string?

```
"C:\temp\".Replace(@"\", "");
```

Comment: I don't think the actual string is "C:\temp\\".  I believe it's actually "SourceDir]\\" and that the logging is converting that.  Otherwise the output of "[SourceDir" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep to preceding slashes, and just remove the last one, you might try:

```
... msiDirectory.TrimEnd('\\');
```

As in:

```
session.Log(" (1): {0}", msiDirectory.TrimEnd('\\'));
```

This will remove any number of backslashes (if there are any), but only if they occur as the last character in the string.

e.g.

```
C:\temp\  --> C:\temp
C:\temp   --> C:\temp
C:\temp\\ --> C:\temp
```

Alternatively, if you wish to remove ALL backslashes (which would be odd for a file path), you could do that easily with:

```
... msiDirectory.Replace(@"\", "");
```

Comment: session.Log(" (1): {0}", msiDirectory.TrimEnd('\\')); gives C:\temp\

Comment: That's good. That points your problem in the direction of @juharr's suggestion.

Comment: can you please elaborate on @juharr`s answer.  Please see edited part.  When doing a System.IO.Path.Combine(msiDirectory, fileName);, it is still adding the double \\ in the path and this does not work.  It gives, C:\temp\\filename.txt How can I handle this?

Comment: The problem seems to be the session.Log() method. I think if you inspect the value of msiDirectory before you make any changes, you'll find the value is actually "[SourceDir]". When you pass that into Log() method, it converts the value to the actual directory path. That's why you can't remove the trailing backslash.

Comment: Also, in your Wix file, are you calling your custom action AFTER calling <ResolveSource .../> ? As in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237051/how-do-i-use-the-sourcedir-msi-property-in-wix

Comment: do you mean <Custom Action ="CopyLogFile" After="InstallFinalize">NOT (REMOVE="ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)</Custom>, I don`t use resolvesource

Comment: Actually, thinking about this - your session.Log() call **is** resolving the [SourceDir], so that can't be the issue. What happens if you replace `string msiDirectory = session["MsiDirectory"];` with `string msiDirectory = session["SourceDir"];` ? Does that change the result?

Comment: You mean to say string msiDirectory = session["SourceDir"]; ? In custom action.. the build fails with this.  I have <Property Id="MsiDirectory">[SourceDir]</Property>  in the wix file

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what you expect (i.e. C:temp instead of C:\temp\) you can use

```
msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Replace("C:\temp\\","C:temp");
```

or best

```
msiDirectory = msiDirectory.Replace(@"\","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `<Property Id="MsiDirectory">[SourceDir]\\</Property>` sets a property named `MsiDirectory` to a value of (literally) `[SourceDir]\\`. If you want `MsiDirectory` to be a copy of the value in `SourceDir`, you must use a custom action to copy it. You can either do that with a type 51 (set property) custom action, or since you're already writing code, just read from `SourceDir` there and write to `MsiDirectory` as relevant.

Once you're working with a value of `C:\temp\` instead of `[SourceDir]`, the rest should make make a lot more sense.

Side note: You might try `session.Log("MsiDirectory: [MsiDirectory]")` to see if you can log the value of the property MsiDirectory without subjecting it to additional formatting. (If the proper overload exists, you may be able to pass a format string containing `[1]` and a record containing the value from msiDirectory.) It appears that the call you are using first does a `string.Format` and then goes through Windows Installers' formatting.